# Rails: Prevent Form from Resetting when attempting to submit form with validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently when I submit a form that has valdidation errors, the form is reset to blank values.  Is there any way to keep the values in the field so the user does not have to reenter the entire form?

my create action:

```
def create
  @quote = Quote.new(params[:quote])
  if @quote.save
    flash[:success] = "Record Created Successfully"

    redirect_to quotes_url
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

my form:

```
<%= form_for @quote do |f| %>
<fieldset>
  <% if @quote.errors.any? %>
      <div id="errorExplanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@quote.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>
        <ul>
          <% @quote.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
              <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
  <% end %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :quote_date, "Date of Quote" %>  <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :quote_date %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :good_through %> <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :good_through %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :quote_number %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :quote_number %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :customer_id, "Customer" %><br/>
    <%= select(:quote, :customer_id, Customer.all.collect {|c| [ c.fname, c.id ] }, :prompt => "Select Customer") %>
  </p>

  <%= f.fields_for :quote_items do |builder| %>
      <%= render 'quote_item_fields', :f => builder %>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Line Item", f, :quote_items %>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

In `QuotesController#new`

```
@quote = || Quote.new
```

This way you can pass @quote instance variable with failed parameter from `#create` to 'new' template, and won't be overwrote with #new.

*Disclaimer: I have not verified this in real code. Just thoughts*

Comment: Yeah. I had Quote.new(params[:quote]) in my #new action.  Apparently that was overwriting the params values in the create action. Thank you for sending me in the right direction.